# Best way to fit this dishwasher under the kitchen counter?

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher, kitchen-counters, cutting

This dishwasher is about a half inch too tall. Cutting a slot into the underside of the counter would solve the problem, and the lip of the washer would hide the cut, but I don't know the best way to actually cut the rectangular chunk out of the material? Hacksaw? Jigsaw? Rotary tool?

Note that the spring and metal brackets on top can both be removed with no ill effects.

**EDIT** - to address some questions in the comments:

- this is a very old home that an acquaintance has just moved into
- this is a second-hand dishwasher from the acquaintance's previous residence
- obviously we want to make a few changes to the countertop and flooring as possible to get it slid into place

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there a layer of flooring you could remove to be able to place the dishwasher on the subfloor instead?

Comment: If a dishwasher was in there and you changed nothing with floor or countertop it should be within the adjustability of the new machines design

Comment: If this is because of new flooring install you should edit the question to include that info. Raising the countertop an equal amount to new floor thickness is an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have level adjustments on the feet , run them in all the way. Maybe the adjusters can be removed. A rasp or float file can be use to remove limited spots on the bottom of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree I lot of dishwashers on the bottom have little round adjusters and you can either take him out or raise them and keep them in check for those and see if you have them in app under your  dishwasher.   I don’t understand how the machine will not fit if you just took out an old one and bought a new one because there should be pretty much a standardize size.  If there are no little round adjusters under the washer then I would remove those screws on the top like you said they can be removed without any problems so I would do that and that may cure your problem as well.  Another question is the blanket or insulation that you have around the dishwasher causing it not to be able to go all the way back to the wall.  I’ve never seen insulation like that On a dishwasher usually that is removed I believe before you put it in.

Comment: My experience is limited (only the dishwashers I've owned) but every one has had insulation.  Your comment made me do some research (again, limited) but it certainly has purpose.  
https://www.hunker.com/12615646/why-do-you-need-insulation-around-a-dishwasher
However, it is also not going to be the cause if this thing not fitting.  To me, this looks like a flooring job where they forgot to take into account the flooring height when replacing appliances (again, mistake I've made in the past).  I got lucky with mine though and was simply able to remove the adjusters.  Hopefully they can too.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this several times.  Unless it is just a matter of lowering the adjustable feet, every time it was because of a flooring change.  Usually from some type of vinyl to tile or hardwood.

If this is the case, and there is flooring extending into the dishwasher space, it will need to be removed and the dishwasher set on the sub-floor.  It is likely that you will have to loosen the countertop enough to raise it a half inch or so to get the dishwasher past the edge of the flooring.

I could, of course, be wrong, but I hope that helps and you can enjoy your new dishwasher.

Come to think of it.  There is one other instance I ran across where a laminate counter top was installed without the blocks that raise it 3/4" so the front lip of the top is even with the top of the cabinets.  This causes the front lip of the countertop to sit 3/4" too low.  It If this is the case, the top needs to be raised 3/4" so that the bottom of the front lip of the top is even with the top of the base cabinets.